# flutter chatting application send image optimization

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, dart-pub

```
class MessageBubble extends StatelessWidget {
  final String? text;
  final String? imageUrl;
  final String senderId;
  final BubblePosition position;
  final String type;
  final DateTime timestamp;
  final bool isUploading;
  MessageBubble({
    this.text,
    this.imageUrl,
    required this.senderId,
    this.position = BubblePosition.middle,
    required this.type,
    required this.timestamp,
    this.isUploading = false,
  });
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: senderId == FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid
            ? CrossAxisAlignment.end
            : CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Material(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: position == BubblePosition.start || position == BubblePosition.middle
                  ? Radius.circular(30.0)
                  : Radius.circular(0.0),
              bottomLeft: senderId == FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid
                  ? Radius.circular(30.0)
                  : position == BubblePosition.end
                  ? Radius.circular(0.0)
                  : Radius.circular(30.0),
              bottomRight: senderId == FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid
                  ? position == BubblePosition.end
                  ? Radius.circular(0.0)
                  : Radius.circular(30.0)
                  : Radius.circular(30.0),
              topRight: Radius.circular(30.0),
            ),
            elevation: 5.0,
            color: senderId == FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid
                ? Colors.blueAccent
                : Colors.white,
            child: Padding(
              padding: type == 'text'
                  ? EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 20.0)
                  : EdgeInsets.zero,
              child: type == 'text'
                  ? Text(
                text ?? '',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: senderId == FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid
                      ? Colors.white
                      : Colors.black54,
                  fontSize: 15.0,
                ),
              )
                  : type == 'image'
                  ? FutureBuilder<String?>(
                future: getImagePath(imageUrl!),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data != null) {
                      return Container(
                        constraints: BoxConstraints(
                          maxWidth: 300.0,
                          maxHeight: 250.0,
                          minHeight: 240.0,
                          minWidth: 280.0,
                        ),
                        child: ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                          child: Image.file(
                            File(snapshot.data!),
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    } else {
                      return Text("Error loading image.");
                    }
                  } else {
                    return CircularProgressIndicator();
                  }
                },
              )
                  : null,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
Future<void> pickAndUploadImages() async {
    List<String> thumbnailURLs = [];
    List<String> imageURLs = [];
    List<Media>? mediaList = await ImagesPicker.pick(
      count: 5,
      pickType: PickType.image,
      language: Language.System,
    );
    if (mediaList != null && mediaList.isNotEmpty) {
      for (Media media in mediaList) {
        File imageFile = File(media.path);
        File? compressedThumbFile = await compressImage(File(media.thumbPath ?? "default_path"));
        if (compressedThumbFile == null) continue;
        String fileExtension = getFileExtension(imageFile);
        try {
          // Upload thumbnail
          TaskSnapshot thumbSnapshot = await FirebaseStorage.instance
              .ref('chatMedia/$chatId/thumbnail')
              .child(DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString() + '.jpg')
              .putFile(compressedThumbFile);
          String thumbURL = await thumbSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
          TaskSnapshot imageSnapshot = await FirebaseStorage.instance
              .ref('chatMedia/$chatId/image')
              .child(DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString() + '.' + fileExtension)
              .putFile(imageFile);
          String imageURL = await imageSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
          thumbnailURLs.add(thumbURL);
          imageURLs.add(imageURL);
        } catch (error) {
          print('Error uploading image: $error');
        }
      }
      await _firestore.collection('private_chat').doc(chatId).collection('messages').add({
        'thumbnailURLs': thumbnailURLs,
        'imageURLs': imageURLs,
        'type' : 'image',
        'senderId': currentUid,
        'timestamp': Timestamp.now(),
      });
    }
  }
```

Both codes exist in different dart files.
This is a chat application.
The purpose of the function I want is to first upload the local image to messagebubble when the user uploads an image, upload it to firestore on the backend, and then load the image from firestore later.

In other words, as a way to improve UX, uploading to the DB and then reloading it takes a certain amount of time, which is inconvenient for users, so we are trying to improve this.

I searched and solved various methods for loading local images, but there were various errors such as not recognizing the local image at all, loading two firestore images, etc.

i did optimization.  but it's didn't work

Comment: Are you looking to optimize the way you're uploading/reading the images from Storage?